# gnuplot histogram: how to offset rotated string above bars

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

For histogram plots, I'm trying to display a rotated string just above the bar top.

I've found posts for displaying a *value* at top of bars and using that technique works - but the rotated *string* is centered at top of bar so extends into bar and I want it to be entirely outside the bar.

Is there a way to offset by string length ?

For data ala

```
  01/06 4 label1
  01/07 5 label2
  01/08 3 label3
```

All the following fail

```
  plot 'test.dat' using 2:xtic(1) with histogram, '' using 0:2:3 with labels rotate by 90 offset char 0,$3
  plot 'test.dat' using 2:xtic(1) with histogram, '' using 0:2:3 with labels rotate by 90 offset char 0,strlen($3)
  plot 'test.dat' using 2:xtic(1) with histogram, '' using 0:2:3 with labels rotate by 90 offset char 0,strlen(sprintf("%s", $3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `help labels`. However, as far as I can see, the options are not explicitely mentioned there but if you check `help label`, there you will see the options `left|center|right`.
For example:

**Code:**

```
### histogram with string label
reset session

$Data <<EOD
01/06   4    "short label"
01/07   5    "a medium label"
01/08   3    "a pretty long label"
01/09   1    "and here now the longest label"
EOD

set style fill solid 0.3
set yrange[0:]
set offsets 0,0,2,0   # left,right,top,bottom

plot $Data u 2:xtic(1) w histogram, \
        '' u 0:2:3 w labels rotate by 90 left offset 0,0.5

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works great.  I had checked the manual but apparently not in right place, since now knowing what to look for I did find 'left' described under 'Label'

Comment: @Jack sometimes it's not obvious where to find the right information. If the answer answered your question, please check it as "acceptable" indicating that problem is solved.

Comment: theozh - thought I had accepted the answer after adding my comment.  Just now checked the "check" and see "you have accepted this answer", but do not see  any change in color as expected.  If there is something else I need to do, let me know.